# If there was no ozone layer, would the temperature decrease all the way from sea level to the mesopause?

Tags: atmosphere, temperature, ozone

The temperature increase with altitude in the stratosphere is caused by the UV radiation absorbed in the ozone layer, isn't it? What if there was no ozone layer? Would temperature keep decreasing beyond the tropopause (which wouldn't exist then) until the mesopause at 53 mi (85 km) above sea level? If so, would the mesopause be even colder than now or what would the temperature profile look like?

Comment: Rather, there is primarily oxygen absoption of UV C <200 nm, breaking Oxygen O2 -> 2 O, which react with another oxygen molecule to form ozone: O + O2 -> O3. Secondarily there  is ozone UV absoption. So better to hypothetically exclude oxygen either.// Some old mercury lamps with unfiltered spectrum created a lot of ozone in the lab room, when a friend of mine have used some in 80s to UV erase EPROM memory chip content.